# Vaadin on Grails Plugin: Vaadin Version

Tags: grails, vaadin

There's already version 7.5.8 out of Vaadin, but the plugin seems to use version 7.5.2 (https://grails.org/plugin/vaadin). Is there any way I could get the latest version in use of Vaadin?

Comment: have you tried excluding `group: com.vaadin` from the plugin and add your own deps?

Answer (score 1):

1. clone the github repo (git clone https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin)
2. change to the new directory (grails-vaadin-plugin)
3. change to the vaadin 7 plugin directory (grails-vaadin7-plugin)
4. update the vaadin version in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy and VaadinGrailsPlugin.groovy
5. run 'grails maven-install' to deploy to your local maven cache
6. update the vaadin plugin version in your project's BuildConfig.groovy [compile(":vaadin:7.5.8")}
7. run 'grails refresh-dependencies' in your project

Comment: 8. create a pull request